# Magento: Filtering a Collection with grouped Clauses

Tags: collections, magento, filtering

I would like to filter a collection with grouped clauses. In SQL this would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE col1='x' AND (col2='y' OR col3='z')
```

How can I "translate" this to filtering a collection with `->addFieldToFilter(...)`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your collection is an EAV type then this works well:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('yourmodule/model_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('col1', 'x')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
        array('attribute'=>'col2', 'eq'=>'y'),
        array('attribute'=>'col3', 'eq'=>'z'),
    ));
```

However if you're stuck with a flat table I don't think `addFieldToFilter` works in quite the same way. One alternative is to use the select object directly.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('yourmodule/model_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('col1', 'x');
$collection->getSelect()
    ->where('col2 = ?', 'y')
    ->orWhere('col3 = ?', 'z');
```

But the failing of this is the order of operators. You willl get a query like `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (col1='x') AND (col2='y') OR (col3='z')`. The `OR` doesn't take precedence here, to get around it means being more specific...

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('yourmodule/model_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('col1', 'x');
$select = $collection->getSelect();
$adapter = $select->getAdapter();
$select->where(sprintf('(col2 = %s) OR (col3 = %s)', $adapter->quote('x'), $adapter->quote('y')));
```

It is unsafe to pass values unquoted, here the adapter is being used to safely quote them.

Finally, if `col2` and `col3` are actually the same, if you're OR-ing for values within a single column, then you can use this shorthand:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('yourmodule/model_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('col1', 'x')
    ->addFieldToFilter('col2', 'in'=>array('y', 'z'));
```

Comment: Thanks clockworkgeek! Because `Mage::getResourceModel('core/url_rewrite_collection')` represents a flat table i had to go the "more specific" way :)

Comment: It's a pity the collections interface isn't always so neat. Sometimes it lends itself to solutions most elegantly.